# Unknown characters when printing text file in c

Tags: c, file, character, codeblocks

I am trying to print the characters from a text file using C in CodeBlock terminal. I use getc and printf. But the terminal shows unwanted characters as well. For example,
when I read,

```
CAAAAATATAAAAACAGGTTTATGATATAAGGTAAAGTATGGGAGATGGGGACAAAAGT
```

It shows,

```
CΘA A A A A T A T A A A A A C A G G T T T A T G A T A T A A G GT A A A G T A T$GhGêG╝A G<AöT G@GñG<G AxC A A A A G T
```

Can any one please state what can be done to avoid this situation.

Comment: Show your code?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I don't think the issue is in the code for this one, see my answer. Still, it's better to **always** include a [mcve] for such questions.

Comment: @Niru your last edit doesn't qualify the question for reopening. You **must** add your code, simplified to a [mcve], so we can actually be **sure** about what the problem is. **Then** the question can be reopened for more answers.

Answer (score 3):

Your text file obviously uses a 2byte [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). If this is on windows, it's very likely [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

`char` in C is a single byte, so a single-byte encoding is assumed. There are many ways to solve this, e.g. you could use [iconv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv). On windows, you can use `wchar_t`(*) to read the characters of this file (together with functions for wide characters like [getwc()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getwc) and if you need it in an 8byte encoding, windows API functions like [WideCharToMultiByte()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) can help.

---

`wchar_t` is a type for "wide" characters, but it's implementation-defined how many bytes a wide character has. On windows, `wchar_t` has 16 bits and typically holds UTF-16 encoded characters. On many other systems, `wchar_t` has 32 bits and typically holds UCS-4 encoded characters.